# Cannot coerce String { class: java.lang.String }

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am trying to send email from the flow and stored all the email addresses in the yaml file like below

```
# Email
email:
  toEmail: "abc.123@gg.org,def.456@gg.org"
  fromEmail: "ms-dev@gg.org"
  ccAddress: "abc123@gmail.com"
```

I am trying use the above values in to the send email connector like

[image]

```
<email:send doc:name="Send" doc:id="fd09c56f-eaed-44c4-ab06-aa0417f2fdbf" config-ref="Email_SMTP" subject="Error with SOW integration between D365 and Salesforce " fromAddress='#[p("email.fromEmail")]' toAddresses='#[p("email.toEmail") splitBy ","]' ccAddresses='#[p("email.ccAddress")]'>
            <email:body contentType="text/html">
                <email:content ><![CDATA[#[vars.emailBody]]]></email:content>
            </email:body>
        </email:send>
```

But when debugging Iam getting the error like below

```
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "Cannot coerce String { class: java.lang.String } ("abc123@gmail.com" as String {class: "java.lang.String"}) to Array" evaluating expression: "p("email.ccAddress")".
Element               : salesforce-proc-SendEmail_Flow/processors/1 @ salesforce-proc:salesforce-proc-implementation.xml:566 (Send)
Element DSL           : <email:send doc:name="Send" doc:id="fd09c56f-eaed-44c4-ab06-aa0417f2fdbf" config-ref="Email_SMTP" subject="Error with SOW integration between D365 and Salesforce " fromAddress="#[p("email.fromEmail")]" toAddresses="#[p("email.toEmail") splitBy ","]" ccAddresses="#[p("email.ccAddress")]">
<email:body contentType="text/html">
<email:content><![CDATA[
#[vars.emailBody]
]]></email:content>
</email:body>
</email:send>
Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION
FlowStack             : at salesforce-proc-SendEmail_Flow(salesforce-proc-SendEmail_Flow/processors/1 @ salesforce-proc:salesforce-proc-implementation.xml:566 (Send))
at listener-flow(listener-flow/errorHandler/0/processors/2 @ salesforce-proc:salesforce-proc-implementation.xml:547 (Flow Reference))\
```

After fixing ccAddresses error I get below error

```
caf9-11ec-b461-025041000001] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error while sending email: Exception reading response
Element               : salesforce-proc-SendEmail_Flow/processors/1 @ salesforce-proc:salesforce-proc-implementation.xml:566 (Send)
Element DSL           : <email:send doc:name="Send" doc:id="fd09c56f-eaed-44c4-ab06-aa0417f2fdbf" config-ref="Email_SMTP" subject="Error with SOW integration between D365 and Salesforce " fromAddress="#[p("email.fromEmail")]" toAddresses="#[p("email.toEmail") splitBy ","]" ccAddresses="#[p("email.ccAddress") splitBy ","]">
<email:body contentType="text/html">
<email:content><![CDATA[
#[vars.emailBody]
]]></email:content>
</email:body>
</email:send>
Error type            : EMAIL:SEND
FlowStack             : at salesforce-proc-SendEmail_Flow(salesforce-proc-SendEmail_Flow/processors/1 @ salesforce-proc:salesforce-proc-implementation.xml:566 (Send))
at listener-flow(listener-flow/errorHandler/0/processors/2 @ salesforce-proc:salesforce-proc-implementation.xml:547 (Flow Reference))
```

Can anyone please suggest what is that I am missing here.

Comment: Please use text instead of screenshots for errors, logs and configurations/flows. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details.

Comment: @aled Updated the question with text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ccAddresses` expects an array. Because you are using an expression to configure that attribute you need to convert the string value from the configuration file explicitly to an array, for example using the `splitBy()` function as you did in `toAddresses`.

Or **if you will only use one address** simply remove the expression and use a property placeholder  (`ccAddresses="${email.ccAddress}"`).

Comment: Thank you that resoved the issue but I am getting other error, I have updated in the question

Comment: I have set the `mail.smpt.starttls.enable` true in the connector configuration. Still get the same error

Comment: That's a different issue, probably related to your specific email server. Please open a new question.